# Responding to a webhook event with raw data

Tags: krl, webhooks

I'd like to write a ruleset that can respond to webhook events with raw data. The event might come in from a URL like the following:

```
http://cs.kobj.net/blue/event/rest/echo/a163x85/?a163x85:kynetx_app_version=dev&body=hi%20there
```

I can use the `send_directive()` action, but that returns a lot of JSON that I don't necessarily want:

```
// KNS Fri Apr  8 19:40:40 2011
{"directives":[{"options":{"body":"hi there"},"name":"echo","meta":{"rule_name":"echo","txn_id":"154CEDCC-6218-11E0-9E71-726A5E50CE3F","rid":"a163x85"}}]}
```

Is there a way to respond with just raw data, rather than with a whole directive structure?

Comment: Used this today, thanks for bringing it up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to use the [Webhook Endpoint](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Webhook_Endpoint) to interact with KNS, not directly signal an event.

You would signal your event like so:

`http://webhooks.kynetxapps.net/h/a163x85.dev/echo?body=hi%20there`

And a rule like so:

```
rule x {
  select when webhook echo
  pre {
    body = event:param("body");
    response = { 'thebody': body };
    rjson = response.encode();
  }
  send_directive("json") with body = rjson;
}
```

For a response like:

```
{"thebody":"hi there"}
```

Note the `.dev` in the URL for indicating the dev version of the app, `echo` as the event name, and the event domain of `webhook`.

The endpoint will even serve it with the proper mime/type for json.

Also note you can return html, xml, js, plain text, and even a redirect. Check the [Webhook Endpoint Docs](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Webhook_Endpoint) for more details.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know there was a webhook endpoint like this. That solves the problem beautifully.

Comment: Turns out, you weren't the first one with this problem. :) Happy to have solved your problem in advance of you having it.